# how do i get the index of a listviewitem in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

```
ListViewItem lvi = FindParent<ListViewItem>(sender as WebControl);
ListView lv = FindParent<ListView>(lvi);
int index = lv.items.IndexOf(lvi);
```

FindParent() goes through the visual tree

I want to get the index of the listviewitem within the listview. Unfortunately, the binding is not allowing me to convert from listviewitem to the bound class. It seems like there should be a simple solution but I cannot find it.

I do not want to select the item, just find its index. Selecting and deselecting is also not good enough. Currently the item is never found, and index is -1. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Delete all that and use proper XAML and DataBinding.

Answer (score 2):

lol I figured it out. Funny how I find the answer 5 minutes after giving up and posting to the internet. Here is it if anyone else is having this same problem.

```
int index = lv.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(lvi);
```

Comment: I have a listview with an itemssource bound to MyBrowserCollection, which is an observablecollection of class MyBrowserControls. here is the link to the datatemplate http://pastebin.com/YHm1v6hs.  As you will see, there are two elements in each datatemplate, a Webcontrol and a gridsplitter.  That's why i have FindParent<ListViewItem>(sender), because I need the listviewitem which is the parent of the two controls up a few levels. The second line isn't really necessary, i could've just called it by name.... therefore it would be.....

Comment: ListViewItem lvi = FindParent<ListViewItem>(sender as WebControl);

int index = browserlistview.itemcontainergenerator.indexfromcontainer(lvi);

just 2 lines, is there a better way to do this using xaml and databinding?

Comment: `<ListView SelectedIndex="{Binding SomeIntProperty}"/>` and you get the seelected index automatically bound if that's what you're looking for... Otherwise just `(sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as YourDataItem`.

Comment: yup, that works alright. When the webcontrol is clicked, MyBrowserControl mbc = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as MyBrowserControl), then I can get int index =  BrowserListview.Items.IndexOf(mbc). Both work, Your way is probably more correct though, thanks.

Comment: @FedericoBerasategui: Your downvote is not helpful, there *are* use cases where low-level access to these things is required. (Concrete example: I am currently developing a generalized Drag&Drop-Handler for ListViews, and this method is exactly what I was looking for.)

Comment: @Heinzi I stand corrected. It's been ages.